# Jest testing issue: not working and says did not exit one sec after the test run has completed

Tags: node.js, express, testing, jestjs

I am currently learning testing, and while using Jest, I encountered an issue that I am unable to resolve. Here's the code snippet that is causing the problem:

server.test.js

```
// __tests__/server.test.js
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../backend/app");

describe("/api/register", () => {
  it("returns status code 201 with some details", async () => {
    const res = await request(app).post("/api/register").send({
      email: "kalitasandeepan123@gmail.com",
      password: "password",
    });
    expect(res.status).toEqual(201);
  });
});
```

app.js

```
const User = require("./models/user");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const { isAuthenticated } = require("./middlewares/auth");
const haversineDistance = require("./haversineDistance");

// Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/api/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ success: false, message: "user already exist" });
    }

    user = await User.create({
      email,
      password,
    });
    const token = await jwt.sign({ userEmail: email }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const options = {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
      httpOnly: true,
    };
    res.status(201).cookie("token", token, options).json({
      success: true,
      user,
      token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
});
module.exports = app;
```

console :

$ npm test

> location_based_service_api@1.0.0 test
> jest

FAIL  **tests**/server.test.js (6.251 s)
/api/register
× returns status code 201 with some details (5003 ms)

● /api/register › returns status code 201 with some details

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

  4 |
  5 | describe("/api/register", () => {
> 6 |   it("returns status code 201 with some details", async () => {
    |   ^
  7 |     const res = await request(app).post("/api/register").send({
  8 |       email: "kalitasandeepan123@gmail.com",
  9 |       password: "password",

  at it (__tests__/server.test.js:6:3)
  at Object.describe (__tests__/server.test.js:5:1)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.328 s
Ran all test suites.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

'This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: You probably need to close your server passed to supertest.